# _pickle.UnpicklingError: invalid load key, 'D'

Tags: python, pickle

I create a udp server and client, and want to get data from server, but I always get this wrong `_pickle.UnpicklingError: invalid load key, 'D'`, I don't know how to solve this problem, please tell me what should I do, thanks.

I use plickle module to dumps and loads my data

client:

```
...
data, server = sock.recvfrom(4096)
data = pickle.loads(data)
...
```

server:

```
...
a = pickle.dumps(a)
sent = sock.sendto(a, address)
...
```

Comment: Is your pickle data smaller than 4096 bytes?

Comment: Yes, total bytes not greater than 4096

Comment: What is `a`? Is it an instance of a class that exists in both programs? Is that class identical in both programs? Are both programs using the same version of Python on the same platform with the same versions of the same libraries installed?

Comment: If that isn't the problem, there's no way we can debug this for you unless you tell us what `a` is and even then you'll probably need to `pickletools.dis` the pickle or similar.

Comment: a is my data want to send, the content is list

Comment: Are the server and client both using the same pickle protocol?

Comment: what is the protocol function? please tell me more information, thank you